# jQuery Validate Remote Error Message

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for form validation. There is a field I want to do remote validate.

Example code:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: "check-email.php"
        }
    }
});
```

When it is not valid, it display "Please fix this field." How can I have custom error message for the remote validate such as "Email address already in used. Please use other email."?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

their documentation seems to show a `message` option. can that be helpful ?

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

example on their site:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    name: "Please specify your name",
    email: {
      required: "We need your email address to contact you",
      email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

here is the solution

```
rules: {
    shopname:
             {
    required: true,
    remote:"code.php",
          },
        }
```

Now in your code.php file-

If input is ok then display **NOTHING**.

if input incorrect then you have to display a **QUOTED** text like-

echo '"This Username is booked You Should Try VIVEK98779797 "';

so now by this code you can **display custom error message by PHP using remote method**

Answer (score 3):

Simply pass an array of messages as a second argument to the validate() function. To specify 
a custom error message for remote validation use the key remote as shown below.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: "check-email.php"
    }
  },
  messages: {
    email: {
      required: "This field is required",
      email: "Invalid Email Address",
      remote: "Email address already in use. Please use other email."
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But it seems doesn't work. Could it be no longer working with latest version (version 1.11.1)?

Comment: @user1995781 Are you sending any response on failed validation from your "check-email.php" file?

Comment: @user1995781 You need to send response from your "check-email.php" file "true" for successful validation and "null" or "false" for failed validation. The response should be in JSON format.

Comment: Yes. Validation everything is working. What I mean is custom error message not working.

Comment: @user1995781 Can you post your code of "check-email.php"?

Comment: My "check-email.php" basically echo "true" or "false" only.

Comment: @user1995781 Do you encode response in JSON? Like so? $arr = array(true); echo json_encode($arr);

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem i found the solution like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#myform" ).validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote:"check-email.php"
              }  
            },
         messages: {
          email:"please fix this field"  
          }
    });
});
```

try this