# jQuery validate - Check if email exists using remote request (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the 'remote' parameter validate jQuery to access a script that checks that the email exists or not.
I checked with Firebug and the request is made, but I can not return and error message in the field.
Below is my Javascript and PHP code:

Javascript:

```
mail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: 'ajax/usuario.checar.mail.php',
                    type: 'POST'
                }
}
```

PHP:

```
if($checar > 0)
{
    // If e-mail exists, error message below
    echo "E-mail já cadastrado!";
    exit;
}

// If e-mail not exists, return true 
echo "true";
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989029/jquery-validate-remote-error-message

Comment: I checked but not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? Any error message in the console? Can you reach php?

Comment: @Masiorama The request is made but the error message simply not appear on the form.

Comment: your javascript is partial. Can you update it? It is impossible to reproduce the error this way.

Comment: This is my full javascript code: http://pastebin.com/M9GpCymw @Masiorama

Comment: You **must** encode the string as JSON. `echo json_encode("E-mail já cadastrado!");`